# What is the POST end point for taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a test script to create (POST) a term for a *Tags* vocabulary using cUrl. That simple script is working fine on Drupal 8.9.20, but it returns a 404 error on Drupal 9.3.0.

```json
{"message":"No route found for 'POST \/entity\/taxonomy\/term\/taxonomy_term'"}
```

What is the POST end point for taxonomy terms?

I tried with different endpoints, but I get the same error message. In Drupal 8, they work.

- http://example.org/entity/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json
- http://example.org/entity/taxonomy/term/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json

In Drupal 9, I'm able to POST for nodes; I'm able to GET for taxonomy terms. It is only the POST for taxonomy terms that is causing problems.
The Drupal 8 and Drupal 9 setups are clean default installations with only the Web Services modules enabled using Drush. Both are using the exact same Drush script.

This is the script I am using to query the end point.

```bash
endpoint="http://example.org/entity/taxonomy/term/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json"
curl --request POST \
  -k \
  -i \
  -s \
  --user "${BOT_USERNAME}:${BOT_PASSWORD}" \
  --header 'Content-type: application/hal+json' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  "${endpoint}" \
  --data-binary "@${json_file}"
```

This is the JSON file used from that script.

```json
{
  "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "http://example.org/rest/type/taxonomy_term/tags"
    }
  },
  "vid": [
    {
      "target_id": "tags"
    }
  ],
  "name": [
    {
      "value": "RESTtag",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are the enabled modules and the resource settings.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you need to drop /entity from your post URL, also be sure non of the taxonomy views is overriding that path.

Comment: Droping /entity doesn't work. I tried that before asking the question. I tried: /taxonomy/term/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json, /term/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json
/taxonomy_term?_format=hal_json. I deleted all the views and still have the same issue.